# Joomla on server shows "it works" page

Tags: joomla

Joomla developers.

I developed an website for myself with joomla on local server. and after a while, I uploaded it to a server that I purchased from a company but it only shows "it works" on a white background.

the address is jeonseungwon.com

I do not get why I got this page.

Comment: You obviously didn't upload it correctly. The website is loading the first index file it sees and it isn't your joomla site obviously.

Comment: Is this about setting database? when moving joomla from local to remote server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following error you're getting on your site:

```
Database connection error (2): Could not connect to MySQL.
```

I pretty self explanatory. It simply means that the setting you have in your **configuration.php** do not match the database. When you "uploaded" your site to your purchased host, you need to ensure that you also upload your database as well, along with creating a database username to assign to it, and ensure the setting match the details in the **configuration.php**